# Get back json response from android management API call

Tags: android, android-management-api

I am using android management api in my android application. Now I want to get the policies of my android app I am using this method `policies.get` for fetching the policy. Now what i want is acually to get the json from response back in my application. This is how i did

```
checkPolicy(ENTERPRISE_ID,name);


 private void checkPolicy(String enterpriseName, String policyId)
            throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Getting policy...");
        String name = enterpriseName + "/policies/" + policyId;
          androidManagementClient
                .enterprises()
                .policies()
                .get(name)
                .execute();

    }
```

Here I am using correct way to get the policy but i don't know how get reponse back? I mean like in this [page](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies/get). I enter the parameters and recieve a json. Now what i need to do in application to  get response json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request should be in the form `enterprises/{enterpriseId}/policies/{policyId}`

And you can save the response into a variable :

```
 var policyJson = androidManagementClient
                .enterprises()
                .policies()
                .get(name)
                .execute();
```